# Django REST framework serialization error on pk field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, restful-url

In my Django REST framework project i have this model:

```
class ml_request(models.Model):
    model_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    p_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    p_description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    p_designation = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default='')
    p_points = models.IntegerField(default=00)
    p_price = models.IntegerField(default=00, blank=False)
    p_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    p_region_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    p_region_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    p_variety = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    p_winery = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='req_owner', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    highlighted = models.TextField()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)
```

then i create my serializer like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from botoapi.models import ml_request, ml_response, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, 
STYLE_CHOICES, ml_logs
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RequestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='request-highlight', format='html')
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = ml_request
        fields = ('id', 'model_id', 'highlight', 'created', 'p_country', 
'p_description', 'p_designation',
              'p_points', 'p_price', 'p_province', 'p_region_1', 'p_region_2', 
'p_variety', 'p_winery', 'owner')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            log_save = ml_logs(l_verbose=validated_data, l_method="CREATE", 
             l_action=validated_data.get("model_id", None))
            log_save.save()
            return validated_data
```

and is my view code:

```
class RequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ml_request.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RequestSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                      IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

bur when i run it and try to add values django return this error:

> AttributeError at /requests/
>   'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
>   Request Method: POST
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/requests/
>   Django Version: 1.11.7
>   Exception Type: AttributeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'

i have the id as PK and i add it in my serializer, someone can help me to wonder why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your `views.py`

Comment: Well i did it. thanks

Comment: I think your definition of id in the serializer is conflicting with the actual id field in the model.

Answer (score 1):

From 3.x onwards,

If you want to add django auto 'id' explicitly in HyperlinkedModelSerializer, you need to use ReadOnlyField (not an IntegerField). Or else you can include it in 'fields'.

```
class RequestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
```

And by default the serializer will include a url field instead of a primary key field. You can explicitly include the primary key by adding it to the fields option.

> The name of the URL field defaults to 'url'. You can override this
>   globally, by using the URL_FIELD_NAME setting.